# Why does my Perl one-liner report "Bareword found where operator expected"?

Tags: regex, perl, string-formatting, syntax-error

I want to convert block size into MB. I am using the `/e` option in my substitution. When I add starting MB in substitution part it giving me the error.

e.g:

This works.

```
 echo "16777216 SELECT" |perl -lane 's#(\d+)(\s+SELECT)#$1/(1024*1024*2)#e; print'
8
```

This giving me the error.

```
echo "16777216 SELECT" |perl -lane 's#(\d+)(\s+SELECT)#$1/(1024*1024*2) MB $2#e; print'
Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near ") MB"
        (Missing operator before MB?)
syntax error at -e line 1, near ") MB "
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Any help fixing the second one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `/e` switch turns the replace expression into a regular perl expression. You need to quote the `' MB'` and use concatenation (`.`) .

```
's#(\d+)(\s+SELECT)#$1/(1024*1024*2) . q[ MB] . $2#e
```

Should work.

Answer (score 6):

Change

```
(1024*1024*2) MB $2
```

to

```
(1024*1024*2)."MB".$2
```

The `/e` modifier tells the engine to treat the substitution field as Perl code.

Comment: The /e modifier expects the replacement to be valid, compilable code.

Comment: @davorg: Was about to change that.