# Replacing multiple occurrences of a char between two string patterns

Tags: regex, perl

I have a file 1.txt with below content

F1,F2,[as1,as2],[as3,as4]

F3,F4,F5,[as5,as6]

I require to write a regex in perl  so that I should change the delimiter ',' inbetween `[' and ']` to `|` .

I tried below, but it did not work.

```
@qr = $st = /\{(.*)(\|)+\}/;
```

where `$st` has the input string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the versions of Perl older than Perl 5.14, you can't but use a regex like

```
echo "[as1,as2,as3],[as4,as5]" | perl -lpe 's/(?:\[|\G(?!^))[^]]*?\K,/|/g'
```

See the [online demo](http://ideone.com/WFqHZj).

**Pattern details**:

- `(?:\[|\G(?!^))` - either a literal `[` or the end of the previous match (`\G(?!^)`)
- `[^]]*?` - zero or more chars other than `]`, as few as possible, are matched
- `\K` - the whole match value is dropped
- `,` - a comma lands in the match (that is replaced with `|`).

For Perl version 5.14 and newer (*where `r` modifier appeared*), you may match the `[...]` substrings with `\[[^][]+]` regex (that matches `[`, then 1+ chars other than `[` and `]`, and then `]`) and perform the replacements inside these matches:

```
echo "F1,F2,[as1,as2],[as3,as4]" | perl -lpe 's/(\[[^][]+])/$1=~s#,#|#gr/ge'
# => F1,F2,[as1|as2],[as3|as4]
```

See the [online demo](http://ideone.com/POUaH2).

Comment: @teser: Have you seen my demo? What output do *you* expect? "It-did-not-work" does not help understanding *how* it should work.

Comment: My apologies. I get the below error.
Bareword found where operator expected at 2.pl line 18, near "s#,#|#gr"

Comment: This issue is related to how you are using the solution in *your code*, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4833203/bareword-found-where-operator-expected).

Comment: perl -lpe 's/(\[[^][]+])/$1=~s/,/|/' str.txt

where
str.txt has the input in it. But output is incorrect

Comment: You should not use the same regex delimiters in the replacement part. Use `#` as in my example. Or enclose it with `{...}`. But be sure to use the same modifiers as in my example above. I see you dropped them from the regex. Have a look at [this demo](http://ideone.com/D9ZvuN).

Comment: I tried the same , but I get the below issue 


echo "F1,F2,[as1,as2],[as3,as4]" | perl -lpe 's/(\[[^][]+])/$1=~s#,#|#gr/ge'

                                                   Bareword found where operator expected at -e line 1, near "s#,#|#gr"

syntax error at -e line 1, near "s#,#|#gr

Comment: Ok, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3923967/why-does-my-perl-one-liner-report-bareword-found-where-operator-expected

Comment: What is your Perl version? `r` modifier appeared in Perl 5.14.

Comment: @tester: The `r` modifier appeared in Perl 5.14. Either upgrade your Perl, or use another solution I posted.

Comment: The new solution will not work if input is like [as1,as2,as3],[as4,as5]

Comment: Ok, I see, the greedy `*` should be replaced with a non-greedy, lazy, one, `*?`. See [the final demo here](http://ideone.com/WFqHZj).

Comment: @tester: Glad it worked for you. Please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: can you tell me why have you used \K and (\G(?!^)

Comment: `\G` matches at the start of the string or end of the previous successful match, it is important to add `(?!^)`  that will subtract the start of string position. `\K` is used for a more convenient replacement, otherwise, I'd have to capture the `[^]]*` part and use a backreference in the replacement. `\K` is just used for convenience. And one more thing: `'s/(?:\[|\G(?!^))[^],]*\K,/|/g'` seems to be the best pattern here as the `[^],]` matches any char but `]` and `,`, and the `*` can be left greedy.

Answer (score 1):

A simple one-liner may solve your task:

input:

```
F1,F2,[as1,as2],[as3,as4]

F3,F4,F5,[as5,as6]
```

`perl -lpe 's/\[(.*?),(.*?)\]/[$1|$2]/g' file`

the output:

```
F1,F2,[as1|as2],[as3|as4]

F3,F4,F5,[as5|as6]
```